# WPF - DataBind TextBlock.Text to Integer

Tags: wpf, data-binding, integer, textblock

I know this a really simple question..

I have a Textblock who's text property I want to be databound to an integer I have in the codebehind.. right now I'm doing this

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlockCompeltedSongsNumber" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
```

Then in c#..

```
            this.TextBlockCompeltedSongsNumber.DataContext = CompeltedTracks;
```

Where CompletedTracks is a public int

What am I missing?

Comment: That should work just fine, what problems do you get?

Comment: The TextBlock does not display anything... it remains empty always...

Comment: @Ryan: What error message do you get though? Look at the Output window for a "Binding Error" when you are running your app. That will help you/us figure out what the issue is.

Comment: There were not Binding Errors in the output window.. Or any other errors

Comment: @Ryan, put a breakpoint at the line and see what the value of CompletedTracks is. Also, I assume there are no typos.

Comment: I did.. I then changed my declartion of CompletedTracks to "public int CompletedTracks = 0;" and as a result the program actually displays 0... but doesnt change it when CompletedTracks changes..

Comment: Binding will work only for property. So check whether CompletedTracks is a field or property. You need to subscribe to INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just made a class that implemented INotifyPorpertyChange

```
    //Global Declaration
information info = new information();
```

later...

```
            this.TextBlockCompeltedSongsNumber.DataContext = info;
```

and the information class

```
public class information : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int failedTracks = 0;
    public int FailedTracks { get { return failedTracks; } set { failedTracks = value; OnPropertyChanged("FailedTracks"); } }
    private int compeltedTracks = 0;
    public int CompeltedTracks { get { return compeltedTracks; } set { compeltedTracks = value; OnPropertyChanged("CompeltedTracks"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in the xaml

```
                    <TextBlock Name="TextBlockCompletedSongs" Margin="5,0,5,0">Completed Songs:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlockCompeltedSongsNumber" Text="{Binding Path=CompeltedTracks}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlockFailedSongs" Margin="5,0,5,0">Failed Songs:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlockFailedSongsNumber" Text="{Binding Path=FailedTracks}"></TextBlock>
```

It seems like a lot of work for something that should be simple... but I couldnt get it to work any other way... I dunno what I was doing wrong :O

Comment: Unfortunately you need to do this. How else is WPF supposed to know that your property changed? If you want the UI to update when you change your property, *something* needs to tell WPF. INotifyPropertyChanged is the usual way of doing that. It'd be wonderful if C# could make properties do this automatically, but they can't, and so you end up writing an awful lot of this sort of thing in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set DataContext too late. After it's rendered.

Wouldn't it better to bind directly to a property and raise PropertyChanged event?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CompletedTracks}"></TextBlock>
```

and set DataContext of the TextBlock's parent to CompletedTracks's owner.

Comment: CompletedTracks owner is the window that this is all happening inside... how would I set that datacontext? this.TextBlockCompeltedSongsNumber.DataContext = this; ??

Comment: in Windows's ctor: this.DataContext = this;